# PDO para DOCTRINE - Haversine formula

Tags: php, pdo, slim

Preciso transferir a consulta em PDO abaixo para DOCTRINE:

```
   $query = $con->query('SELECT *,
            ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians('.$latitude.') ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians('.$longitude.') ) + sin( radians('.$latitude.') ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance, city_name
            FROM event INNER JOIN city ON event_city_id = city_id
            WHERE event_sin_active = 1
            ORDER BY distance');
```

Até o momento consegui reescrever no doctrine parte dessa query.
O problema aparece ao inserir no SELECT a ***Haversine formula***  conforme os perguntas:
[SQL search using Haversine in Doctrine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973878/sql-search-using-haversine-in-doctrine) e [How to calculate distance using latitude and longtitude?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21084886/how-to-calculate-distance-using-latitude-and-longtitude)

As duas tabelas no banco de dados usadas são Event e City

```
    CREATE TABLE `event` (
  `event_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `event_name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `event_image` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `event_city_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `latitude` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `longitude` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `event_tax_service` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `event_user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `event_sin_active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`event_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;



 CREATE TABLE `city` (
  `city_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `city_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`city_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Ao tentar executar a query abaixo, o sistema retorna uma tela em branco e não informa qual a exception.
**Qual a maneita correta de escrever essa query?**

```
$qb = $entityManager->createQueryBuilder();
        $qb->select("e, e.eventCityId,c.cityName, (6371 * ACOS(SIN(RADIANS($latitude)) * SIN(RADIANS(e.latitude)) + COS(RADIANS($latitude)) * COS(RADIANS(e.latitude)) * COS(RADIANS(e.longitude) - RADIANS($longitude)))) as distance")
            ->from('\App\Entity\Event', 'e')
            ->innerJoin('\App\Entity\City', 'c', Join::WITH, $qb->expr()->eq('e.eventCityId', 'c.cityId'))
            ->where('e.eventSinActive = 1')
            ->orderBy('distance', 'ASC');
```

Comment: Ajudaria muito você por o erro na pergunta. Caso não saiba como exibir o erro, é o caso de pesquisar se já não tem solução no site, ou abrir uma pergunta específica sobre isso. Antes, veja o log de erros do PHP. O problema pode não estar na query em si, e sim no jeito que passa as variáveis ou no resto da sintaxe. Em vez de fazer o select, troque por um echo e veja a saída. Dê uma lida na documentação do Doctrine que é bem provável que haja um meio de exibir os erros. Além disso, você tem o log do MySQL e do PHP pra conferir. Mas um simples echo resolve nesses casos, em vez de executar.

Comment: Tão relevante quanto a estrutura do banco são as classes das entidades que mapeia a estrutura do bd  em objetos PHP.